# Using of arithmetic and logical operators in switch statement

Tags: c++, if-statement, switch-statement, logical-operators, arithmetic-expressions

I want to use logical operators in switch statment.
For Example:
" x is greater than 3 and is less than 7 "
Using it in If statement.

```
if(x > 3 && x < 7)
  {
    //something
  }else if(x 11 3 && x < 15){
         // anything
  }
```

How can I use it in switch statement.
And how to use arithmetic operators.
**UPDATE**
Now how we use it in switch. Can there is not way to use it in switch.

Comment: What language is this?  JavaScript?  C#?  Java?  C?

Comment: I believe `case:` expressions have to be constant.  So, the correct way is to use the `if` statement.

Comment: My question is that can we use expression in switch or not. if yes then how???

Comment: Whatever book you're using to learn C++ isn't doing a very good job. `switch` accepts an expression. `case` does not.

Comment: @RaymondChen Actually, just to clarify that a bit - `case` can accept an expression, as long as it's a constant expression that is fully defined and computable at compile time...

Answer (score 2):

You mean, something like this?

```
switch (some_var)
{ case 4 : // fall through
  case 5 : // fall through
  case 6 : do_something();
          break;
  default : do_something_else();
           break;
}
```

It's ugly, and gets worse the larger a range you want to cover, but since `switch` `case`s must be constants, that's one way to do it.

Another way would be:

```
switch ((some_var > 3) && (some_var < 7))
{ case 0: do_something_else(); break;
  default: do_something(); break;
}
```

But that'll only work if you have exactly one range you want to test. There are other ways if you have a set of equally-sized intervals that are spaced equally far apart, using some basic arithmetic, but we'd have to know a bit more about the specific problem(s) you're trying to solve...

Frankly, though, I think the `if` construct is the better solution...